# Intent-Filter cannot open both http and content

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I can't seem to get my `intent-filter` to open both from an `http` and a `content` scheme. I have my `intent-filter` setup to look for a certain file extension (ex: ".riley"), but when I set my `data` section to look for both an `http` scheme and `content` scheme, it refuses to open it through `http`. When I set it up to look for just `http`, it won't open with `content`. When I don't specify a `scheme`, it only opens through `file` and `content`, but ignores `http`.

Here is my basic setup without a specified `scheme`:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
    android:host="*"
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.riley" />
```

How can I get access to open my application from the specified path extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using multiple intent-filters instead of defining both schemes within the data tag.

I have had a similar issue and could resolve it by using the [Intent Intercept app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) and checking which parts of the intent didn't match.
I have found that apps tend to omit the file extension when opening intents via the content scheme, that might be part of your problem as well.

Comment: Yes. This IS the correct answer. I had to post another, more thorough, question, yesterday. Where were you on the 21st?! ;) Thank you!

Comment: [Here is the question that I mentioned above, for the sake of future googlers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15625955/1292230). Can you also add in an example of multiple `intnent-filters` for anyone searching? I think that will determine the upvote :)

Comment: Ahhh. I just did it for you. Its easier this way! But voting on the question is always courteous! ;)