# Open my application for a particular file and URL extension - intent-filter isn't working as intended

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

### Question:

**How can I get my application to open a file and url extension, unconditionally?**

I am at my wit's end with setting up my `intent-filter` as none of it is really making any sense. My end goal is to open up anything that has a `path` ending in a certain extension. For the sake of an example, let's choose *".riley"* as my goal extension.

### My Base `intent-filter`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="*"
        android:mimeType="*/*"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.riley" />
</intent-filter>
```

**This currently works to open from `file` and `content`.**

### Issue #1: pathPattern

For starters, it doesn't seem as though the `data` parameter `pathPattern` does anything, as I have set:

```
<data
    android:host="*"
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.riley" />
```

.. but I can still open `Intent`s with `Uri` paths that do not end in *".riley"* under the `file` and `content` scheme.

A couple example paths that my application opened using this `intent-filter` are:

`Path: /storage/sdcard0/Download/MyApp.apk`
`Path: /messagesByAccount/1`

The "Path: " was just my own addition in the log for clarity. The first is from gmail under the `file` scheme and the second is from gtalk under the `content` scheme. Given that, I am already confused about how `intent-filters` work.

**The `pathPattern` is being ignored on `file` and `content` schemes.**

### Issue #2: Opening in a browser

I've tried to get my application to open *".riley"* extensions from browsers, however redirecting links don't have a MIME-type, so I removed the `mimeType` value from the `data` pattern (I had `android:mimeType="*/*"` earlier, as the MIME-type isn't consistent) and that allowed me to open from redirecting URLs just fine.

The problem came when I tried to open a direct *".riley"* URL from the browser (eg: http://thisisnotarealdomainname.com/myfile.riley) and the option to open from my application was gone. Adding the `mimeType` value back to my `data` pattern allowed me to open from a direct URL.

**The `intent-filter` won't let me open both direct and indirect URLs.**

### Issue #3: scheme

I would like to be able to open from a number of different scheme types (eg: `http,`file`,`content`), but as soon as I remove`scheme`altogether, it disqualifies my application from opening the`http`scheme and when I specify`scheme="*"`, it disqualifies my application from opening ANY scheme. I've also tried adding more`data` patterns, but I get the feeling as though only one is taken into effect, as that doesn't help me at all.

So, specifying `http` will allow for `http`, but obviously hasn't allowed either `file` or `content` and not specifying the `scheme` disables `http`.

**I cannot open from all different schemes.**

To reiterate, ***how can I get my application to open a file and url extension, unconditionally***, given these *complications*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue #1: `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.riley" />` is simply invalid. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path):

> [pathPattern is] meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.

Issue #2: "however redirecting links don't have a MIME-type" should be incorrect, unless the Web server is seriously broken. An HTTP redirect itself does not have a MIME type, but that should be handled by the browser itself, as until the browser handles the redirection, it has no idea whether the URL points to something that it should handle (e.g., a Web page) or something that should be downloaded. The result of the redirect -- the HTTP 200 OK response -- should have a MIME type. If you are convinced that redirected URLs to downloads do not work, create a sample project demonstrating the error and post it somewhere for review.

Issue #3: "I cannot open from all different schemes." --  use multiple `<data>` elements with multiple `android:scheme` attributes, in separate `<intent-filter>` elements.

For example, the AOSP Music app has:

```
    <activity android:name="AudioPreview" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="-1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You will notice that the action, category, and MIME type are the same in all three `<intent-filter>` stanzas; only the `android:scheme` attribute varies.

Now, the `file` scheme for this Music app example will only work if some local file manager attaches the appropriate MIME type to the `Intent`; Music does not attempt to use `android:pathPattern` to match file extensions. In fact, Google rarely uses `android:pathPattern`. There is one occurrence in the AOSP Calendar app:

```
        <intent-filter
           android:priority="50">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPrefix="/calendar/event" />
           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPrefix="/calendar/event" />
           <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPattern="/calendar/hosted/.*/event" />
           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPattern="/calendar/hosted/.*/event" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But that's pretty much it. Certainly others have tried it -- there are a bunch of questions here on StackOveflow covering its use.

Comment: I hope I can respond cleanly enough in the comments! For issue #1, I will clarify in an edit of my question, when I said "As well as other parameters", I meant that the `data` tag had `scheme` and `host` declared, the same way they were declared in the example above it. Again, I will edit that in. For issue #2, I know one example of a web script that doesn't return a MIME-type is when the web page redirects with Javascript's `window.location`. I can specify a `<data android:scheme="http"/>` `intent-filter` to catch it and verify that the MIME-type is `null`.

Comment: As for issue #3, what you've said works wonders and it makes a lot more sense than the documentation did for me. So thank you so much!

Comment: Also, the reason that I left out the `scheme` and `host` from my `<data/>` snippet was in hopes of cleaning up the question to only show relevant information and making it easier to read through, however, it seems to have had the opposite effect.

Comment: @RileyE: "redirects with Javascript's window.location" -- yeah, I am not surprised that this is giving you difficulty, as that's not an HTTP redirection. With respect to issue #1, try to find some open source Android app that uses `pathPattern` (Google Code Search, I miss you so!) and see how it handles it.

Comment: Google Code Search may be gone, but at least there is still `http://symbolhound.com/`! But I will just have to suffer the loss on the `window.location`. Everything else is working as expected now. So, thank you!