# XAMARIN-ANDROID Extracting Zip File From My Android App

Tags: android, xamarin.android, intentfilter

I need to enable my app to extract the zip file and I want to open my app when a zip file is clicked (selected) from the device.
I have Created and IntentFilter after reviewing some posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097734) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626398)

```
    [Activity(Label ="Zip")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
                            DataScheme ="file",
                            DataHost ="*",
                            DataPathPattern = "*\\.zip",
                            DataMimeType = "application/zip"
                            DataPathPattern = "*\\.zip",
                            DataMimeType = "application/zip"
    )]
```

And the code for activity goes here :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        
        var uri =  Intent.Data.Path;
        Toast.MakeText(this, uri, ToastLength.Long);
       
    }
```

Problem: when I select the zip file my app is not getting launched.
Reference Documentation : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: when I select the zip file my app is not getting launched.

Comment: from the linked answers - I see that you didn't add the Xamarin analog of `<data android:scheme="file" />`

Comment: also a `<data android:host="*" />`

Comment: I have updated the question,  the issue prevails.

Answer (score 1):

I did many test and finally find that after modify my code like this it works :

```
DataMimeType = "*/*"
```

And add a condition in order to restrict your app only works for .zip file :

```
DataPathPattern = ".*\\.zip"
```

Complete code :

```
[Activity(Label = "Zip", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
                        DataScheme = "file",
                        DataHost = "*",
                        DataPathPattern = ".*\\.zip",
                        DataMimeType = "*/*"
)]
```